# What’s the difference between “to VERB” and “to be VERBed”?

Tags: differences, infinitives, passive-voice

What is the difference between these two statements:

1. A new version of Java is ready **to install**.
2. A new version of Java is ready **to be installed**.

Comment: In what Java is trying to tell you, there's no difference at all.

Comment: Notice that it's not "*to be install". You hafta add _-ed_ as well as _be_. That's because it's a Passive infinitive. And, since _ready_ can take either an active infinitive with _Tough_-Movement **or** a passive infinitive with Equi. They both mean the same thing.

Comment: Yep that completely makes sense John. How about the meaning of "to be verb+ing" - For example what is the difference between: 1. He is the worst person to organize this. 2. He is the worst person to be organizing this? do you think both are the same?

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, there's no practical difference. Either the subject (the Java setup tool) and object (the Java runtime) of the verb *install* could be called "a new version of Java", so either is fine.

Here's another example where it makes more difference:

- The man is ready to climb.
- The man is ready to be climbed.

In the first sentence, the man is has prepared himself to climb something (a wall perhaps, or maybe a tree). In the second sentence, the man is prepared for something (perhaps a small child) to climb onto him.

There's a third, more ambiguous statement which could cover both possibilities:

- The man is ready for climbing.
- A new version of Java is ready for installation.

Comment: `In the first sentence, the man is has prepared himself...` Is `is has` a typo?