# Meaningless/Placeholder Verb?

Tags: terminology, vocabulary, convention

In some fields of study, there are various placeholder nouns/proper nouns---basically nouns that are conventionally used in an example but are understood not to correspond to an actual object.

In economics examples you frequently see 'widgets'.

In law you have 'John Doe' or 'Blackacre'.

In computer science you see 'foo' and 'bar' used as variable names.

Is there, in any field of study, a *verb* that fulfills the same role? That is, a verb that does not actually correspond to an action, and is conventionally understood to be some sort of placeholder? I can vaguely remember encountering such a verb in the past---something that ended in -ulate or -ize, but I can't for the life of me remember what it was.

Comment: I can't imagine a case where the actual verb is *not* important (contrary to manufacturing processes, where what is made is not an important aspect of the sentence and *widget* suffices). A sample sentence may help here.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, An example from the literature is "He umm[...] thingoed with High Distinction, uhh[...] graduated." (Powers, 1991) This is not specific to a field of study, but is rather a general example of placeholder verb use as a result of lexical access failure.

Comment: @JEL That's the problem: *widget, John Doe, foo, bar* are not lexical access problems: the exact term is simply irrelevant to the context. In your example, the verb is crucial and *thingy* doesn't perform the same function as the OP's examples.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, an example from this site, where 'verb' is itself used as a placeholder/fillin for "any of a set of" verbs: [What’s the difference between “to VERB” and “to be VERBed”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188763/what-s-the-difference-between-to-verb-and-to-be-verbed). I expect, finally, that popular linguistics will provide the readiest examples, although oblitive verbs are used with a variety of functions in, for example, Georgian.

Comment: In CS contexts, I often see "***frobnicate***".

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how common it is these days, but when I was in college 30-35 years ago the popular placeholder verb was **to frob**; if you wanted to sound more sophisticated, the longer version **to frobnicate** could be used.

This word also did double duty as a noun, being used similarly to **widget**.

[Hacker's Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=g80P_4v4QbIC&pg=PA206&dq=%22frob%22%20hacker%27s%20dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv7M_Iup3LAhWIGj4KHaSjB9IQ6AEILzAA#v=onepage&q=%22frob%22%20hacker's%20dictionary&f=false)

Comment: "frobnicate" was the first word that came to my mind.

Comment: I've also heard "frobulate" used in the wild as a metasyntactic verb, which could be the "ulate" word that OP is trying to remember.

Answer (score 1):

To extend the computer science example you gave, someone may want to demonstrate a certain feature or technique applicable to methods. If it is a general point about method definition or invocation and the actual method is not important, then if foo and bar are given as class names, the method is often referred to as `foo.doSomething()` or `bar.doSomeWork()`. These seem to fit your requirement as verb placeholders, although they are not single words.

The closest I can think of in everyday usage is using an obscure or nonsense word as a placeholder, so maybe you are remembering a word like `discombobulate`?